# Inserting strings into linked list structure

Tags: c

I'm trying to dynamically add strings to a linked list. (I don't know how many strings there are going to be).

Here is my code so far that I've found:

```
struct node
{
int data;
struct node *next;
}*start=NULL;
//------------------------------------------------------------

void creat()
{
char ch;
 do
 {
  struct node *new_node,*current;

  new_node=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));

  printf("nEnter the data : ");
  scanf("%d",&new_node->data);
  new_node->next=NULL;

  if(start==NULL)
  {
  start=new_node;
  current=new_node;
  }
  else
  {
  current->next=new_node;
  current=new_node;
  }

 printf("nDo you want to creat another : ");
 ch=getche();
 }while(ch!='n');
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------

void display()
{
struct node *new_node;
 printf("The Linked List : n");
 new_node=start;
 while(new_node!=NULL)
   {
   printf("%d--->",new_node->data);
   new_node=new_node->next;
   }
  printf("NULL");
}
```

If I want to add strings to the linked list structure do I only change:

```
    struct node {
      int data;
```

to:

```
  struct node {
    char abc[256];
```

And change all the %d to %s? Is it that simple?

Comment: Well, when you tried it, did it work?

Comment: It did not, just wondering what else I need to change?

Comment: it might be that simple !! but why don't tell us what you actually want us to answer about this question-simple/not simple????

Comment: Unrelated, move the declaration of `current` *out* of (above) the loop. As written now your code invokes undefined behavior by eval/dereference of an indeterminate pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah! it will also work. But the better one is to keep a temporary buffer which will store the string inputs. Now whenever you get a string just dynamically allocate (using `malloc()`)that number characters + 1 char to that pointer. And copy the buffered input to it using `strcpy()`. Look at this code snippet.

```
struct struct_name
{
   char *data;
    ....
};
char buffer[MAXBUFFERSIZE];
scanf("%s",buffer);
struct struct_name * temp= (struct struct_name*) malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen(buffer)+1));
if(temp==NULL)
{
    //error.
}
strcpy(temp->data,buffer);
.....
```